# Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Cannot complete this action

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

i'm new on sharepoint 2013:

In my sharepoint solution which is created from visual studio , I created a project that contains the data model of my solution : I put in this project custom fields, custom types as well as custom lists that my solution requires.

then I created 3 features in this project :

The first feature which is **a site scoped feature** contains **all custom types and custom fields** of my solution, its name is *Feature_ContentTypes_Fields*.

The second feature which is **a Site Scoped feature** contains **all list definitions of my custom lists** ***( in which I added "its name is Feature_ContentTypes_Fields" as feature activation dependency)*** , its name is *Feature_ListDefinitions*.

The last feature which is **a web scoped feature** contains **all list instances of my custom lists** ***( in which I added "Feature_ListDefinitions" as feature activation dependency)*** , its name is *Feature_ListInstances*.

***Result :***

1/ successful build.

2/ failed deploy

Here is the output of visual studio while deploying the solution:

> ------ Build started: Project: Model, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------   Model -> C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\ProxymSPIntranet\SPIntranet\Model\bin\Debug\Model.dll
>   Successfully created package at:
>   C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\ProxymSPIntranet\SPIntranet\Model\bin\Debug\Model.wsp
>   ------ Deploy started: Project: Model, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ Active Deployment Configuration: Default   Skipping deployment step because a pre-deployment command is not specified.   Recycle IIS
>   Application Pool:   Recycling IIS application pool 'SharePoint -
>   1111'...   Retract Solution:   Deactivating feature
>   'Model_Feature_ListDefinitions' ...   Deactivating feature
>   'Model_Feature_ContentTypes_Fields' ...   Retracting solution
>   'model.wsp'...   Deleting solution 'model.wsp'...   Add Solution:
>   Adding solution 'Model.wsp'...   Deploying solution 'Model.wsp'...
>   Activate Features:   Activating feature 'Feature_ContentTypes_Fields'
>   ...   Activating feature 'Feature_ListDefinitions' ...   Activating
>   feature 'Feature_ListInstances' ... Error occurred in deployment step
>   'Activate Features': Cannot complete this action.
>
> Please try again.
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: check your output window as well and see where exactly the error is surfacing from. ctrl+w,ctrl+o shortkey opens the output window when deployment is underway

Comment: the error is surfacing while activating the features , exactly the feature that contains list instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check if the list instance is included in any other features because when you add a sp related item to the solution visual studio automatically adds it to a feature.

-or-

Elements File of the List Definition Should Contain The Below:

```
<ListTemplate
  Type="10999"
```

Check if they are in line with the List Instance's Element File Attribute As Below:

```
<ListInstance
  TemplateType="10999"
```

They should be the same.
Similarly The Content Type Element File would have The Below Attribute:

```
<ContentType ID="0x0100E8F7E7893379472DB2522B0FCDF0C836"
```

This should be the same as the Content Type ID inside the list instance's Schema.xml file:

```
<List Url="Lists/FlatStructuredNavigationListDefinition" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" EnableContentTypes="TRUE" RootWebOnly="TRUE">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentType ID="0x0100E8F7E7893379472DB2522B0FCDF0C836"
```

Check These and Deploy This should Work i had the same issue.

Comment: All list instances are included in the same feature , also all list definitions are in another feature and all custom fields as well as content types are in a third feature.

Comment: @Rihab BEN CHHIBA Check the Edited Answer and let me know if it was helpful

Comment: Always the same problem

Comment: please post a snapshot of the error console as well. it should have some more helpful messaegs. what you have posted is pretty ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem with deploying was related to the Name attribute of the Field nodes. I had Name attributes with spaces, which SharePoint somehow didn't like. No error was given, but I noticed that when I commented out the Field nodes in the Schema.xml file deploying worked. So I spent a lot of time trying to debug this, and finally I found out that deleting the spaces did the trick. So instead of writing

```
< Field Name="My Field Name" >
```

write

```
< Field Name="MyFieldName" >
```

Comment: I had a similar problem where there was a field named "R" that somehow got in there. *This field did **not** show up in the Visual Studio List Column Editor*